# Apache wamp, zend framework installation issue (permission issue and more)

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, httpd.conf, virtual-hosts

I am trying to install zend framework very very naive looked up in the internet for setting but when i apply those settings it doesn't work. I get the following error

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

let me go step by step what I did

1. Installed Zend framework
2. added following line in this file `"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"` file..

   ```
   127.0.0.1       test
   ```
3. un-commented the following two lines of code from `httpd.conf`

   ```
   Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
   LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
   ```
4. add the following few lines in `httpd-vhosts.conf`

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName test
       DocumentRoot "C:/Workspace/zendy/public"
       SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
       <Directory "C:/Workspace/zendy/public">
           DirectoryIndex index.php
           AllowOverride All
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
       </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

After this when i restart my wamp server i get the error message which i mention at the top...

after getting the error message I started from scratch and after every step i check if i get the the same error.

what I have found is if i put back # sing in front of this line `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` it works fine but as soon as i un comment that line again same error... dont know why ... b

by the way i ran `test/` and `localhost/` both worked and showed my the localhost page...

Please Note that i am running windows 8.1 64 bit and very latest version of wamp server i think 2.5 with apache2.4.9 and php5.5.12 and mysql5.6.17 if that is any helpful for you to solving this issue..

Any idea?

Comment: Check your Apache error log for more details on that error. Your config looks fine to me. Also, what URL are you loading in your browser to produce that error message?

Answer (score 1):

This is worked for me. You wanna try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@zendpro
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/zendpro/public"
    ServerName zendpro
    ErrorLog "logs/zendpro-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/zendpro-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You don't think `all` would include `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: I dont know exactly about that if you think it's wrong than i will edit my answer.

Comment: I already have `Allow from all` line an i added `Order Allow,Deny` and `Allow from 127.0.0.1` but no same error by the way thanks for taking time and trying answering this... thanks for the effort @IndrasinhBihola